# spring-boot-actuator disable csrf

Tags: spring-security, csrf, spring-boot-actuator

I used spring-boot-actuator with different port like following

```
server.port=8080
management.port=8989
```

And in application, I want to use `enable-csrf=true`, but I don't want to use `csrf` in actuator port. because I want to use bulk POST request to jolokia.

Only excluding `/actuator` is not smart.

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/actuator/**");
```

Like following property is good for me (bt `management.security.enable-csrf` is not exist).

```
security.enable-csrf=true
management.security.enable-csrf=false
```

Is there any good solution?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do and it's a little tricky... [Possible workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143703/spring-boot-management-port-and-spring-security)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a different management port, you can simply disable CSRF for that:

```
@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static RequestMatcher allOf(RequestMatcher... requestMatchers) {
        return new AndRequestMatcher(requestMatchers);
    }

    private static RequestMatcher not(RequestMatcher requestMatcher) {
        return new NegatedRequestMatcher(requestMatcher);
    }

    private final ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties;

    public MySecurityConfiguration(ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties) {
        this.managementServerProperties = Objects.requireNonNull(managementServerProperties);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(
                allOf(CsrfFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER, not(accessingManagementPort())));
        // other configuration
    }

    private RequestMatcher accessingManagementPort() {
        return httpServletRequest -> httpServletRequest.getLocalPort() == managementServerProperties.getPort();
    }

}
```